# Write/Log Hybris SOAP responses to new file

Tags: logging, soap, sap-commerce-cloud

My goal is to write/log/transfer a specific SOAP responses to a new file.
Which file should I modify so I can specify the new directory of the new file?

Thank you

PS: sorry if I cannot elaborate it more. I'm still new to Hybris.

Answer (score 0):

Below example saving flexiblesearch class debug log to different file. You need to adding logging capability to you SOAP service/client then configure it like below.

```
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.type=RollingFile
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.name=FlexlogAppender
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.fileName=${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/Flexlog.log
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.filePattern=${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/Flexlog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.layout.pattern=%m%n
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.policies.type = Policies
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.policies.time.interval = 1000000
log4j2.appender.FlexlogAppender.policies.time.modulate = true

log4j2.logger.flexible.name = de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch
log4j2.logger.flexible.level = DEBUG
log4j2.logger.flexible.appenderRef.stdout.ref = FlexlogAppender
log4j2.logger.flexible.additivity = false
```